# HP ALM 12.5 installation fails with 'Unable to validate DB connection parameters' error. Help needed

Tags: database, hp-alm

We are trying to install HP ALM 12.5 on a Windows Server 2012 OS.

We have pre-requisite components .Net framework 3.5,4.5, JRE 1.8

During installation, we face an error `Unable to validate DB connection parameters`.

Checked with vendor, but they are repeatedly pointing to DB only.

However, nothing seems to be wrong with the db. we were able to make connections using SQL Developer and Express. Able to view table schema

Tried installing with `SYSDB` role, however that also fails making connection. On the listener we find some traffic from the app machine, in which we are attempting an installation.

We are so confused as to whether it is a App server issue or DB server issue. Port checks were done and no question of firewall. All open.

Any suggestions here is much appreciated !!

- Db details: Oracle 12.1.0.2 Enterprise
- DB server: Unix
- App server: Win 2012 Server standard
- ALM: 12.5 for HP PC 12.5

Answer (score 0):

Check, please, in ALM installation if you are using SID or Service Name of your Oracle instance. 
By default you should provide service name - but you can use SID by modifying Connection string directly (put SID instead of ServiceName).
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9vFu.png) - see screenshot.

Also you can check installation log at User folder\IA_logo for additional information on specific issue you met.